# JMS VirtualProperty with Param

Tags: api, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have an API backend project build with symfony 2.8, doctrine and JSM Serializer. I have an m-m relation, beetween user and book.

What i want is, when i serilize all my book, have an [virtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) that told me if a user have a book.

So i need to pass to the funcion of book entity isPossesed() the user object, so i can see if that user is in array of users that have that book.

The problem is that when i serialize with JSM i don't know how pass a param the the method.

Somethings like this:

```
 /**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
 */
public function isPossessed(User $user)
{
    /* some code
   */   
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Don't think that is possible but, you can add event listeners https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system and add if you need something

Comment: Did your Book Entity has a getUsers method ? If yes, using this getUsers method in isPossessed will fix the problem ?

Comment: this is not a good problem solve for me, i need the possesion status of one user, i think is too much expensive calculate for each User. That i did is write own library to add and serialized object some virtual property.